# How to authenticate with Dynamics Nav web service from LotusScript

Tags: web-services, lotus-domino, lotusscript, dynamics-nav

Running Lotus Notes Domino 8.5.2. I have created a LotusScript web service consumer from a wsdl provided by a Microsoff Dynamics Nav server.

In a LotusScript agent I have this code

```
Dim nav As New Noteswebservice_port_n2()
Call nav.Setcredentials("DOMAIN\username", "password")


Dim res As String
res = nav.Createorder("123", "", "test", "CH")
```

The problem is that I get 401 Unauthorized, when calling CreateOrder.

I have tested the web service from Visual Studio, and it works with the same credentials as used in the agent.

I suspect that Lotus Domino and Dynamics doesn't use the same authentication method. I have tried to enable NTLM on Dynamics, but same result. I have no idea what to do next.

Any ideas?

Comment: May be there is another method mor authentication like nav.SetWincredentials or something?

Comment: @MakSim Setcredentials is the only method for setting credentials in the Noteswebservice class

Comment: Maybe there something like UseDefaultCredentials

Comment: Which NAV version?

Because you can have a second service tier for this which is using NavUserPassword authentication instead of Kerberos or have second tier where you set the Use NTLM to yes

Comment: @azatoth We are running on Nav 2015 (8.0). A second service tier, does that mean that we can have both authentication types running?

Comment: Yes, you can have as many service tiers as you want...and any of them can have different Credential Type. Create new service tier with the tool: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh165851(v=nav.90).aspx) or using PowerShell: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672911(v=nav.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft is using [WS-Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security) in most Web Services by default. I don't know how it is with Dynamics Nav, but I assume it.

Complete description how to use with IBM Notes from Java:

[Extending IBM Domino Web Service Consumers to support SOAP Authentication (Java)](http://www.itwu-demo.net/web/itwublog.nsf/default.xsp?documentId=550FFDDBD8E99174C1257D81004DD4E0)